# Delete whole document for matching objectId in array of objects - MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The structure of my document looks like this in MongoDB :-

```js
{
_id : "7464bbuiecdhbjdje"
client : "MJMK"
users : [
   {_id : "1234" , name : "first user"} 
 ]
}
```

I would like to remove the whole document for matching `users._id`. In this case, for a user with `_id` `1234`,the whole document needs to be removed. I have been unable to find any efficient function that does this in Node using mongoose. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `Model.deleteOne({ 'users._id': "1234" })` (where `Model` is the variable representing your mongoose model )? Make sure that your `_id` has the correct type as you defined in the schema

Comment: What exactly is the structure of `users`? Is that a list of objects? Does each object have an `_id` entry in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [deleteMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/).

This will delete all documents containing the matches query, in this case a user with matching `_id` in the users array. Our query will be utilizing Mongo's [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to access the array like so:

```
Model.deleteMany({ 'users._id': "1234" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
db.collectionName.remove({"users._id":{_id:"1234"}})

Comment: What if it is not guaranteed that `users` has exactly one element in the array?

Comment: check it out: db.collectionName.remove({"users._id":{_id:"1234"}})

Answer (score 0):

From the shell following works. Isn't it possible to do the same in node?

```
db.collectionname.find({ "users": { $elemMatch: { "_id": "1234" } } })
db.collectionname.remove({ "users": { $elemMatch: { "_id": "1234" } } })
```